# Get mysql column of a clicked item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have searched endlessly for an answer but have found none. I am trying to get the id of a clicked item. The item that I am clicking is from mysql database and has been displayed through a for loop. When the item is clicked I am taken to another page. In this page I want to utilize the id from the clicked item to get other information from that row in mysql database; this much I can do. The problem is getting the id from the clicked item and sending it.

This is the most recent way that I tried:

First I displayed the items from mysql.

```
<?php 
   $query = "SELECT `video` FROM `challenge_name` ORDER BY `id`";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   if($result = mysql_query($query))
    {
       for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
          {
              $id = $i;
              $code = "<div id=\"challenge_preview\"><h7 class=\"challenge_preview_item\"     
                        id=\"challenge_preview_name\"></h7><a href=\"challengeprofile.php\">  
                        <video        
                        class=\"challenge_preview_item\" id=\"challenge_video\" 
                        src=\"".mysql_result($result, $i)."\"></video></a></div>";
               echo $code;
          }
         }
    else
     {
       die('Couldn\'t connect'. mysql_error());
      }
?>
```

Than I put the id in a hidden form so that I could attempt to POST it to the other page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
                </form>
```

On the script.php file that is included in both pages, I put

```
$(#challenge_video).click(function(){ <?php $id = $_POST['id']; ?> ;});
```

And on the page that the id is being posted to I put

```
<?php 
   include 'script.php';
   echo getChallengeData('name', 'id', $id)
?>
```

Please help, Thank you

These are the edits

```
<div id='challenge_previews'>
                <?php 
                    $query   =   "SELECT `video` FROM `challenge_name` ORDER BY `id`";
                    $result  =   mysql_query($query);
                    if($result = mysql_query($query)) 
                    {
                        for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) 
                        {
                            $id = $i;                 
                            echo "<div id=\"challenge_preview\"><a href=\"challengeprofile.php\" id=\"".base64_encode("mysalt".$id)."\"><video class=\"challenge_preview_item challenge_video\" src=\"".mysql_result($result, $i)."\"></video></a></div>";
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        die('Couldn\'t connect'. mysql_error());
                    } 
                    ?>
                    <form action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="GET">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14">
                    </form>
                </div>
```

This is the code for page 2

```
<h1 id="challenge_profile_name">
                    <?php 
                        $id = substr(base64_decode($_GET['id']),6);
                        echo getChallengeData('name', 'id', $id);
                    ?>
                </h1>
```

This is the code for the getChallengeData method in the core.inc.php

```
function getChallengeData($field1, $field2, $field3)
{
    $query = "SELECT `$field1` FROM `challenge_name` WHERE `$field2` = '$field3'";
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
    {
        if($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field1))
        {
            return $query_result;
        }
    }
}
```

That error that I'm getting has to do with the implementation of the getChallengeData method on page 2. The error says

> Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ChallengeNetworkWebsite\core.inc.php on line 42

Comment: You are not echoing the `$id` for one thing, so anything in that function that is based on that `$id` won't work.

Comment: If I echo the $id then it will be displayed on the webpage. How would I echo it without displaying it on the webpage?

Comment: To pass the id from one page to the next, maybe try encoding it on the first page, then decoding it on the second. Either that or you will have to come up with some sort of sessionizing method.

Comment: Your .click function is blank... It seems you're trying to run PHP inside JavaScript. PHP runs on the server when the page is displayed.

Comment: You need to send the string in the link, not as the id: `<a href=\"challengeprofile.php?id=".base64_encode("mysalt".$id)."\">`

Comment: Forget about the javascript stuff. What you have for javascript won't mask the id anyway, just set the link as: `challengeprofile.php?id=".base64_encode("mysalt".$id)`

Comment: The previous error is fixed but now I get an error that says. "Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 10 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ChallengeNetworkWebsite\core.inc.php on line 42"

Comment: On which page? The `challengeprofile.php` page?

Comment: Yes on the challengeprofile.php page

Comment: I put the code for page two and for the method that I'm getting the error at above

Comment: Echo the `$query` in your function and see what the SQL statement is writing out. See if it looks normal.

Comment: When I echo it out nothing comes up, just the error message.

Comment: No the query statement. In the function type `echo` before the statement: `echo $query = "SELECT $field1 FROM challenge_name WHERE $field2 = '$field3'";`

Comment: This is what it says  "
SELECT `name` FROM `challenge_name` WHERE `id` = ''" The $id is empty.

Comment: The id should be filled, correct?

Comment: Yes the id should be the id of the video from page 1

Comment: Ok, remove the encoding from the first page, copy what I have updated for the second or view source on your page 1 and see if your id's are properly printing out on the first page.

Comment: The ids on the first page are all printing out properly. But now I am getting more errors on the second page after removing the encoding. The errors say "Notice:  Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ChallengeNetworkWebsite\challengeprofile.php on line 88"

Comment: Man it is really tough to diagnose the issue without actually seeing it live. What you are trying to do is very straight-forward. I would have to fiddle with it in live to see what is happening...